# How do I set the `search` URL parameter in SAPUI5 OData requests?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I want my SAPUI5 ODataModel to send OData requests of the form

```
https://<my-server>/<my-service>/<my-resource>?search='lalaland'
```

There are tons of examples how to add a filter with `model.filter(new Filter(...));` but this is *not* what I want. Filtering means I directly address a certain property with a certain comparator. Searching means I address the resource in general and let the OData service decide which properties to search, and how.

The one thing that seems to be possible is:

```
model.bindRows(..., { "customData": {"search": "lalaland"}});
```

But this is also not what I want because that sets the search term once when the model is created, but cannot update it later on when the user enters.

Funnily, SAPUI5's own implementation of the SmartTable performs exactly the kind of query I want - but doesn't reveal a possibility how I could do that without a SmartTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one solution:

```
oList = this.byId("list"); // or oTable
oBindingInfo = oList.getBindingInfo("items"); // or "rows"
if (!oBindingInfo.parameters) {
  oBindingInfo.parameters = {};
}
if (!oBindingInfo.parameters.custom) {
  oBindingInfo.parameters.custom = {};
}
oBindingInfo.parameters.custom.search = sValue;
oList.bindItems(oBindingInfo);
```

However, I don't specifically like the `bindItems` part. Looks a bit over-the-top to require this to re-bind the whole entity set again and again. So leaving this question open in case somebody has a better idea.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the right answer: you apply this on the binding as a custom parameter! Be careful with the code above, as you might override other existing stuff/parameters (i.e. expand) on the binding...

Comment: @Florian Did you ever find the correct solution for this problem? I have tried this solution, although I am actually trying to use the search on a suggestionItems aggregation on an input field. Have tried with different API calls, but it is not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This is as good as it got. Though truth be told I haven’t been writing much UI5 JS since then, so didn’t pursue this topic aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on bindItems or bindRows depending what control is, something like this:

```
oList = this.byId("list"); 
oList.bindItems({path: '/XXXX', parameters : {custom: {'search':'searchstring'}}})
```

Comment: There is no bindRows on the model. The List has an items aggregation and thus it’s possible to call oList.bindItems(...), but that’s pretty much what @Florian has already suggested. Therefore your answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I use it on Table. In his case is a List, so He can use oList.bindItems({path: '/XXXX', parameters : {custom: {'search':'searchstring'}}}).. I corrected the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it has to be $search and not $filter?

The [OData V4 Tutorial](https://sapui5nightly.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/426ff318051a465191c861b51a74f00e) in SAPUI5's Demo Kit uses

```
onSearch : function () {
            var oView = this.getView(),
                sValue = oView.byId("searchField").getValue(),
                oFilter = new Filter("LastName", FilterOperator.Contains, sValue);

            oView.byId("peopleList").getBinding("items").filter(oFilter, FilterType.Application);
        },
```

Comment: Your example filters for entities whose `LastName` `contain`s the string `sValue`. That's okay for the minimalistic SAPUI5 examples. However, real life is more complex. SAP OData services are nowaways built on top of CDS views. These CDS views declare what properties of entities shall be searched (through annotations), and how (fuzziness, ranking). Filtering would ignore all of these details. Only `search` respects them.